# @TestInstance vs @DirtiesContext

Tags: spring-boot, junit

Junit5 has introduced [@TestInstance](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestInstance.html) annotation to manage the lifecycle and reuse of application context.

How does this relate to the existing [@DirtiesContext](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dirtiescontext) mechanism?

I couldn't find anything that compares the practical use of these two.

Is `@TestInstance` meant to replace the `@DirtiesContext`?

Is it using `@DirtiesContext` under the hood?